# How to improve this atomic orbitals manipulate box output?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, color, output

I made this Manipulate box to show the atomic orbitals in the $(x, z)$ plane:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

NormFactor[n_, l_] := Sqrt[Factorial[n - l - 1]/(2 n Factorial[n + l])]

Psi[n_, l_, m_, u_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := NormFactor[n, l] Exp[-u/2] u^l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, u] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]

u[x_, z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]
theta[x_, z_] := ArcTan[z, x]

Manipulate[
  DensityPlot[
  Abs[Psi[nn, nl, nm, u[x, z], theta[x, z], 0]]^2,
  {x, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20},
  Frame -> None,
  Axes -> True,
  Ticks -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 120,
  ColorFunction -> "GrayTones",
  ImageSize -> {800, 800}
  ],
  {{nn, 1, Style["n :", 12]}, 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{nl, 0, Style["\[ScriptL] :", 12]}, 0, nn - 1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{nm, 0, Style["m :", 12]}, -nl, nl, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:
[image]

The code works, but it is a bit slow on my fast M2 Mac (I'm using **Mathematica 13.2**), and the output is a bit crude to me.  How can I improve the output color shades and style?  I would also like to add some level curves to have a better feel of the probabilities gradations.  Currently, I don't know any proper options for the DensityPlot to add level curves or to get a nice mesh.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Using `ContourPlot` instead of `DensityPlot` may be a good alternative.  However, using a color gradation like `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]` gives a strong white region, instead of a black region.  What's wrong here?  I'm having issues with the colors gradient on the density plot, that I would like to invert (from black to white, instead of white to black).

Also, is there an option to get a random dots distribution instead of a smooth shade of grays, to simulate the electron count probability?

Comment: Change your functions `Psi`, etc to pure functions. This will speedup code a bit. Problem with colors can be solved with correct definition of `PlotRange`

Comment: @Rom38, can you be more specific about the color range?

Comment: To keep the control variables in the allowed ranges, modify the Manipulate to `Manipulate[nl = Min[nl, nn - 1]; nm = Clip[nm, {-nl, nl}]; DensityPlot[ ...`

Comment: @Cham, The correct settings of `PlotRange` around the min/max values of your z-values allows you avoiding this overlighting of white areas.

Comment: @Rom38, I don't understand your comment.  The $z$ values are the same as for $x$.  The wave function spreads over all of the 2D euclidian space.  I could plot the squared wave-function over any part of 2D space.  In other words, there is no min or max value of $z$.  However, there are min/max values for the squared wave function itself: $|\psi|_{min}^2 = 0$ and $|\psi|_{max}^2 < 1$.

Comment: @Cham, your z-value on the plot is a value of wave function. Adjusting the limits for plot, your can achieve better gradients.

Comment: @Rom38, then please can you offer an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To accelerate code we can first generate all images as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

NormFactor[n_, l_] := 
 Sqrt[Factorial[n - l - 1]/(2  n  Factorial[n + l])]

Psi[n_, l_, m_, u_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
 NormFactor[n, l]  Exp[-u/2]  u^l  LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2  l + 1, 
   u]  SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]

u[x_, z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]
theta[x_, z_] := ArcTan[z, x]


Do[Do[Do[
     orbit[nn, nl, nm] = 
       DensityPlot[
        Evaluate[
         Abs[Psi[nn, nl, nm, u[x, z], theta[x, z], 0]]^2], {x, -5, 
         5}, {z, -5, 5}, Frame -> None, Axes -> True, Ticks -> None, 
        PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", 
        ImageSize -> {400, 400}, PlotRange -> All, 
        Exclusions -> None];, {nm, -nl, nl, 1}];, {nl, 0, nn - 1, 
    1}];, {nn, 1, 5, 1}];
```

Then we can manipulate `orbit`

```
Manipulate[
 orbit[nn, nl, nm], {{nn, 1, Style["n :", 12]}, 1, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{nl, 0, Style["\[ScriptL] :", 12]}, 0, 
  nn - 1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{nm, 0, Style["m :", 12]}, -nl, nl, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

For a black on white appearance we can use scheme

```
Do[Do[Do[
      orbit1[nn, nl, nm] = 
        DensityPlot[
         Evaluate[
          1 - Abs[Psi[nn, nl, nm, u[x, z], theta[x, z], 
              0]]^2], {x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, Frame -> None, 
         Axes -> True, Ticks -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
         ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
         PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None];, {nm, -nl, nl, 
       1}];, {nl, 0, nn - 1, 1}];, {nn, 1, 5, 1}];

Manipulate[
 orbit1[nn, nl, nm], {{nn, 1, Style["n :", 12]}, 1, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{nl, 0, Style["\[ScriptL] :", 12]}, 0, 
  nn - 1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{nm, 0, Style["m :", 12]}, -nl, nl, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: It's working very well.  But how do you make the output as black shades on a white background, with high contrasts to better see the orbitals?

Comment: The images are quite different from OP, which are correct? Compare with OP's image for `n=3;l=1;m=1;`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Please, pay attention that we used scale `{x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}` while OP used `{x, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}`. If we apply this scale to my code we will see green aura around central image. Also in OP's code there is no option  `PlotRange -> All` that leads to the wrong appearance in combination with  `ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"` since white area in his image is clipping region.

Comment: Using **ColorNegate** inside the **Manipulate** box almost give the black on white background output I prefer, but it also add a black frame all around.  What would be a proper way of achieving a black pattern on a white background?

Comment: @Cham There are many scheme in option `ColorFunction`.  Could you explain what color do you need?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I simply need to get a black/gray shape on a white background, instead of a whitish shape on a black background.

Comment: @Cham Ok! See update to my answer.

Comment: Yep, it's much better now, thanks!  Just for some polishing: is there a way to increase the contrasts?  There are subtle variations in the orbitals (see for example $n = 5$, $\ell = 1$ and $m = 0$).  I would like to increase the visibility of these regions.

Comment: Let try `1 - Abs[Psi[nn, nl, nm, u[x, z], theta[x, z], 0]]` for contrast.

Comment: Owa!  Removing the exponent is too much!  There are now strong white lines, which are unphysical.  I need to keep the 2 exponent in there.