# How to accentuate subtly colored regions in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I'm having troubles in adjusting the colors shades/contrast/hue of the following typical plot:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there are two dark regions above and under the central part.  I need to accentuate their luminosity (on the black background/first image) to see those areas more clearly, just as shown on the Wikipedia page; see this [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#/media/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png), for the orbital `(3,1,0)`.

Or equivalently, darken the pale yellowish regions on the white background (second image) if possible.

The graphics have been created with **Mathematica 13.2**, using a version of the code from [300318](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300318/how-to-improve-this-atomic-orbitals-manipulate-box-output):

So how can I make the darker regions to stand-out, i.e to be more visible?  I prefer a dark region on a white background (like the second image), and I may accept to increase the central part too to reveal the subtle regions.

Comment: Check ColorFunction and ColorFunctionScaling.

Comment: Are your wave functions same as on Wikipedia?

Comment: @azerbajdzan, yes, the plots are the same, except for the color shades.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with color function you use but with the definition of wave functions you use. On Wikipedia they most likely used a different definition.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, nope, the wave function is exactly the same.  It is given in the upper-right corner of the Wikipedia image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Simpler version of the code with `ColorFunctionScaling -> {0, Pi^2}` and for some reason also plot points had to be increased to `PlotPoints -> 300` to achieve the same quality.

```
NormFactor[n_, l_] := Sqrt[Factorial[n - l - 1]/(2 n Factorial[n + l])]

Psi[n_, l_, m_, u_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
 NormFactor[n, l] Exp[-u/2] u^l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, 
   u] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]

u[x_, z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]
theta[x_, z_] := ArcTan[z, x]

With[{nn = 3, nl = 1, nm = 0}, 
 DensityPlot[
  Abs[Psi[nn, nl, nm, u[x, z], theta[x, z], 0]]^2, {x, -15, 
   15}, {z, -15, 15}, Frame -> None, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
  Ticks -> None, PlotPoints -> 300, ColorFunctionScaling -> {0, Pi^2},
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImageSize -> {400, 400}]]
```

---

[image]

With `ColorFunction -> GrayLevel`:

[image]

With `ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1 - #] &)`:

[image]

**Old version:**

So I think that they are simply clipping the range of the color gradient (that also explain the big white areas on their images).

The constant `0.005637338004403787` is the max value of the function and the clipping constant is `Pi^2` or could be just, say, `9` or `10`. Also you have to use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` for a proper effect of clipping of the gradient.

```
With[{nn = 3, nl = 1, nm = 0}, 
 DensityPlot[Pi^2/
    0.005637338004403787` Abs[
     Psi[nn, nl, nm, u[x, z], theta[x, z], 0]]^2, {x, -15, 
   15}, {z, -15, 15}, Frame -> None, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
  Ticks -> None, PlotPoints -> 120, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImageSize -> {400, 400}]]
```

---

[image]

My image is almost unrecognizable form the one on Wikipedia:

[image]

With `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]` you get:

[image]

Comment: @Cham: The real depiction is your image. They increased contrast in some parts but then loose contrast elsewhere... in the white areas which seem now be constant, but in fact they are not constant as can be seen on your original image.

Comment: Please, could you explain the **ColorFunctionScaling -> {0, Pi^2}**?  Why $\pi^2$?

Comment: @Cham: I think it is just coincidence, I tried to find a constant that resembles the Wikipedia image the most and it turned out to be near $\pi^2$, but as I wrote also in my answer it could be `9` or `10` without too much difference. The constant just determines the clipping point in the gradient. If you use `1` as the constant you get exactly your original image without any clipping.

Comment: Just for a last step polishing, what if you want to use a reversed **GrayLevel** as shade?  Currently, the option **ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]** produces a yellowish gray.  I would like to get a white background, instead of that beige looking version (see your last picture above).

Comment: @Cham: I added those cases into the answer.